# How to replaces a menu when screen size shrinks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a horizontal menu.

I want to replace this menu with a dropdown menu when the screen width drops below a certain point.

I am not talking about a responsive menu i.e a menu that automatically adjusts itself.

Most responsive tutorial are about responsive menu. I want to create a similar effect but I want to completely replace the horizontal menu with a dropdown list.

Thanks

Comment: This menu is going to be "responsive" by design... What have you tried?

Comment: The principle the same: using media queries hide menu show select box.

Comment: What specifically do you not know how to do? This seems like a general task, not a specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're confused about the terminology. What you are asking for **is** a responsive design, i.e. once the window shrinks below a certain width, do something different.

Have both elements on your page, one hidden by default, and use responsive CSS to hide/show the element you want based on browser width. For example:

```
.menuDrop{ display:hidden; }
.menuHoriz{ display:block; }

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .menuDrop{ display:block; }
  .menuHoriz{ display:hidden; }
}
```

Stacy, for your own clarification, what I believe you are saying you don't want is a fluid-only design, i.e. where the menu simply shrinks with the browser window. A menu being fluid is a different thing from whether it is responsive. @jainchetan's 'MeanMenu' example is both fluid (it initially shrinks with the window) and responsive (at a certain point, the design changes in a stepwise fashion), rendered with Javascript instead of CSS.